# Find and split a string by the first character that is not 0

Tags: php, string, pattern-matching, substring

I wanted to know how I could split a string based on the first character that is not 0, e.g.

```
$ID = ABC-000000160810;
```

I want to split the id so it looks like this:

```
$split_ID = 160810;
```

I tried to just get the last 6 digits, however the problem was that the 6 digits might not always be consistent, so just need to split based on the first non-zero. What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using a regular expression:

```
$id = 'ABC-000000160810';
preg_match('/-0*([1-9][0-9]*)/', $id, $matches);
$split_id = $matches[1];
```

Comment: Regex on a simple task and no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ltrim](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) if you only want to remove leading zeroes.

```
$ID = ABC-000000160810;
$split_ID = ltrim($str, '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ltrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) to remove leading characters.

```
$id = 'ABC-00001234';
$numeric = ltrim(mb_substr($id, mb_strpos($id, '-') + 1), '0');
echo $numeric; // 1234
```

The above requires the `mbstring` extension to be enabled. If you encounter an error, either enable the extension or use the non-multibyte functions `substr` and `strpos`. Probably you should get in the habit of using the `mb_` string functions.

This should also work:

```
const CHAR_MASK = 'a..zA..Z-0';
$id = 'ABC-00001234';
$numeric = ltrim($id, CHAR_MASK);
echo $numeric; // 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

For your example "ABC-00000016081" you might use a regex that would match the first part up until you encounter not a zero and then use `\K` to not include the previously consumed characters in the final match.

[`[^-]+-0+\K[1-9][0-9]+`](https://regex101.com/r/dz4I1t/1)

- `[^-]+` Match not a `-` one or more times using a negated character class
- `-` Match literally
- `0+` Match one or more times a zero (If you want your match without leading zeroes you could use `0*`)
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the reported match
- `[1-9][0-9]*` Match your value starting with a digit 1 -9

[Test](https://3v4l.org/iIvFn)

Answer (score -1):

You can substr off the ABC part and multiply with 1 to make it a number.

```
$ID = "ABC-000000160810";

Echo substr($ID, 4)*1;
```

Comment: This assumes that the prefix is always 4 characters long. If true, then `substr` + `ltrim` is preferrable. Also doing type conversion by multiplication is hacky. Use (int) "string" instead ...

Comment: @FuzzyTree You do understand your code can fail in the same way.